# About the compilation problem of Kaleidoscope in llvm tutorial

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am learning llvm.

I am trying to compile the code in Kaleidoscope Tutorial 3.6.
https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

I got some errors, but I don't know what to do.

```
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--cxxflags'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--ldflags'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--system-libs'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'core -o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'toy'
```

By the way, I compiled it under Windows.

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but I would assume the backticks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) does not work properly in your console.
You can try to call `llvm-config --...` separately and then call `clang++` providing the output of the `llvm-config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you get this error is that your shell does not interpret your command correctly.

See:

```
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
```

Thus flags that should be passed to llvm-config are passed to clang.exe.

See:

```
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--cxxflags'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--ldflags'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--system-libs'
clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '--libs'
```

To solve this issue make sure to get llvm-config on you machine and make sure that you use a command line that supports the correct shell semantics. Example of such shells would be git bash or mingw.

Comment: The error means that `clang++` is interpreting `llvm-config` as an argument and thus trying to read a file named `llvm-config` in the current directory (which of course doesn't exist). That means that the backticks weren't interpreted properly by the shell. It does not mean that `llvm-config` isn't installed.

Comment: That is true. I will remove the first line. It is incorrect as you say (Last part is regarding the backquotes. I was imprecise. I will edit)